# Python code to execute the expression when either A or B or both files is selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pysimplegui

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to use pandas and pysimpleGui to create a project. However, my coding didn't work, any advice would be greatly appreciated.
And the project logic is:

- User will need to select either the Customer ID list or Special Price List and then hit the 'Convert' button it will convert the selected file into the correct format.
  -These are the requirements:
  For Customer ID list:
- Must have only 1 column
- If the header isn't CUS_ID then show the replace button:
- If replace button is clicked then the first row will be replaced, if the button isn't clicked then the header will be created.
- If the header is CUS_ID then notify the user under the status bar.
  For Special Price List:
- Must have 3 columns and the header is: 'PROD_CD','UT_PRICE','EXP_DATE'
- the last column is date format mm/dd/yyyy
- If the header isn't correct then show the replace button:
- If replace button is clicked then the first row will be replaced, if the button isn't clicked then the header will be created.
- If the header is correct then notify the user under the status bar.
  The transfer button will run either the Customer ID list or the Special Price list or both are selected.
  And below are my coding:

```
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def main():
    sg.theme('SystemDefaultForReal')
    layout = [                  
    [sg.FileBrowse('CUSID',size = (15,2),file_types =(('Excel File', '*.xlsx'),), key='cusid', enable_events=True), 
        sg.FileBrowse('SPECIAL PRICE LIST',size = (18,2),file_types =(('Excel File', '*.xlsx'),), k='SPlist', enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Button('Convert', key='submit'), sg.Button("Cancel", k='cancel')],
    [sg.StatusBar('', size=(50,1), key='status', justification='center'), sg.Button('Replace Header', key='-replace-', visible=False), sg.Button('Replace Headers', key='-replace2-', visible=False)]   
    ]
    #create the window
    window = sg.Window("Special Price Converter", layout, element_justification='center', finalize=True, icon=r'C:\Python\apps\specialpriceconvert\icon.ico')
    cusidHeader = ['CUS_ID']
    SPlistHeader=['PROD_CD','UT_PRICE','EXP_DATE']
    butt_down = False
    butt_down2 = False
    cusidReplace = False
    SPlistReplace = False 

    #file validation function:
    def validation(filename):
        file= values[filename]        
        validation.df = pd.read_excel(file, header=None) #header = None will show 0 at header
        col_count = len(validation.df.columns)
        if filename == 'cusid':
            header = validation.df.iloc[0,0]
            if col_count == 1:
                #RETURN THE FIRST ROW VALUE
                if header == cusidHeader[0]:      #iloc[row_index, column_index]      
                    window['status'].update('CUS_ID header already exist')
                    window['-replace-'].update(visible=False)                                                   
                    return False   
                else:
                    window['status'].update('Header: ' + header , visible=True)
                    window['-replace-'].update(visible=True)
                    return True
            else:
                window['status'].update('Error: selected file has more than 1 column!', visible=True)
                window['-replace-'].update(visible=False)                
                return False
        
        elif filename == 'SPlist':
            header = validation.df.iloc[0].to_list() #append first row to a list.
            if col_count == 3:
                if  header == SPlistHeader:
                    window['status'].update('Special Price header already exist') 
                    window['-replace2-'].update(visible=False)
                    return False 
                else:
                    window['status'].update('Header: ' + str(header) , visible=True)
                    window['-replace2-'].update(visible=True)                                                                              
                    return True                                     
            else:
                window['status'].update('Error: selected file must have 3 columns!', visible=True)
                window['-replace2-'].update(visible=False)
                return False

    while True:  # Event Loop
        event, values = window.read()        
        #Close window:
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'cancel'):
            break  
                
        elif 'cusid' in event: #if CUSID is selected
            #Validation CUSID:   
            validation('cusid')
            window['-replace2-'].update(visible=False)          

        elif 'SPlist' in event:
            #Validation SPlist:
            validation('SPlist')
            window['-replace-'].update(visible=False)

        #if clicked replace and cusid file is valid:
        
        elif event == '-replace-':                                               
                butt_down = not butt_down              
                window['-replace-'].update( button_color='snow4' if butt_down else 'snow')
                if butt_down:                                    
                    cusidReplace = True                
                    window['status'].update('cusidReplace is: '+ str(cusidReplace), visible=True)
                else:                    
                    cusidReplace = False
                    window['status'].update('cusidReplace is: '+ str(cusidReplace), visible=True)  

        elif event == '-replace2-':           
                butt_down2 = not butt_down2              
                window['-replace2-'].update( button_color='snow4' if butt_down2 else 'snow')
                if butt_down2:                                    
                    SPlistReplace = True                
                    window['status'].update('SPlistReplace is: '+ str(SPlistReplace), visible=True)
                else:
                    SPlistReplace = False
                    window['status'].update('SPlistReplace is: '+ str(SPlistReplace), visible=True)
                      
        elif 'submit' in event:             
            #If only CUSID file is selected and CUS replace button is select:
            if cusidReplace and validation('SPlist') is False:
                print('Cusid Replace button is off and SPlist does not exist')                       
                # excel_export('cusid')
            #If both files are selected:
            elif cusidReplace is False and validation('SPlist') is True:
                print('Cusid Replace button is off and SPlist exist')
            elif SPlistReplace and validation('cusid') is False:
                print('SPlist Replace button is off and Cusid does not exist')
            elif SPlistReplace is False and validation('cusid') is True:
                print('SPlist Replace button is off and Cusid exist')

    window.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please consider specifically stating what's not working and what you tried to fix it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I don't know how to write a code if file A is selected then execute A's expression, if B is selected then execute B's expression and if both file is selected then execute both A & B expression

Comment: `my coding didn't work` means nothing, any detail for it ? It looks like that the using of `sg.FileBrowse` is wrong, no `target` option defined will be default to previous one element at the same row or last one element if no previous one, confirm what event generated by `print` statement in your event loop. Check document on https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/